# Apache alternatives with per-directory SSLVerifyClient

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, web-server, ssl-certificate

My application requires per-directory verification of SSL client certificates (i.e. when user requests /foo we require they have a client certificate and verify it, but when they request /bar we don't care if they have a client cerficiate).  Apache has nice support for this, as the SSLVerifyClient setting can be applied on a per-directory basis, and apache will do SSL renegotiation in this instance to require the certs when needed, but not prompt for a certificate when accessing other directories.

My question is: which other web servers have this capability?  Using apache to fulfil the SSL handling requirement is OK, but it is not my only requirement and I would like to know what the other options are.

Comment: Lighttpd, base on bug track and their wiki, should have support for client cert for some years. However, I am not able to find any useful info on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

As a negative response, `nginx` only supports `ssl_verify_client` at the `http` and `server` scopes, so it *can't* do per-directory SSL client certificates.